# run cmake with a txt file

Tags: c++, cmake

When I run my C++ program I need it to open a text file stored in my root directory. How can I make CMake to execute the program I have written with the text file?

When I build my program with Makefile alone, I use the command

```
./"executable" src/"txt file"
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a post build job.

Comment: I would say to keep your concerns separate. Your build tool should build. Pick something else to run it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, by far the simplest would be to just modify your main function. As it stands you main function must be grabbing the filename from the command line arguments. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const auto filename = argv[1];

  // Do stuff with filename
  std::cout << filename;
  return 0;
}
```

What you probably should do is to just modify that file to use some default filename when no argument is provided:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const auto filename = argc < 2 ? "/root/something.txt" : argv[1];

  // Do stuff with filename
  std::cout << filename;
  return 0;
}
```

Depending on how complicated you want to get, you could also let that filename be specified in your CMakeLists. Just add a definition like

```
set(DEFAULT_FILENAME "/root/something.txt")
target_compile_definitions(my_target PRIVATE "DEFAULT_FILENAME=\"${DEFAULT_FILENAME}\"")
```

and then take the filename like a macro in your main function:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const auto filename = argc < 2 ? DEFAULT_FILENAME : argv[1];

  // Do stuff with filename
  std::cout << filename;
  return 0;
}
```

To summarize... It sounds like you want to have one executable to be built with the filename into it. The aforementioned approaches will accomplish that.

However, there is a much simpler solution... just create a script that runs the file you want. For example, just throw your code

```
./"executable" src/"txt file"
```

into a script `run.sh`

Then make that script runnable (assuming Linux) with

```
chmod +x run.sh
```

and just run that script:

```
./run.sh
```